# Is "the" article needed to fill a gap in a sentence "Martha writes ... of all" (best / the best)?

Tags: definite-article, superlatives

I've come across a test question recently, asking to fill a gap:
"John writes well.  Jack writes better than John.  Martha writes ... of all." (best / the best).

Is it correct/acceptable to omit "the" article here?

> Martha writes *best* of all.

Or it has to be only with "the" article:

> Martha writes *the best* of all.

Comment: Both are OK. Some people might say 'the' is redundant, but it isn't wrong.

Comment: The version without the definite article seems to flow better, and also has better parallelism with the previous two sentences.  If the test question has you choose between those two alternatives, I'd pick the one without 'the.'

Comment: @QuackE.Duck, so did I and got -1 point :)  "The" article was required.

Comment: @NowhereMan Yikes - just saw your previous comment.  I would have lost a point there too.  Apologies if I misled you, but it seems like the test question itself might be flawed